# How to use regular expressions with dplyr's select helper functions

Tags: r, regex, dplyr

It is straightforward to use dplyr to select columns using various helper functions, such as `contains()`. In the help file for these functions the argument is referred to as a 'literal string'. However, is it possible to use regular expressions instead?

The following example works:

```
library(dplyr)
iris %>%
   select(contains("Species"))
```

The following regex example does not:

```
# Select all column names that end with lower case "s"
iris %>%
   select(contains("s$"))

# Not run
data frame with 0 columns and 150 rows
```

I would like to know if using regular expressions in dplyr select helper functions is possible and, if so, their implementation.

If this isn't possible, I will except an answer using an alternative method (e.g., base or data.table). For background, my ultimate aim is to use a `summarise_at()` function or equivalent to sum all columns that end in a number (i.e, regexp `[0-9]$`).

Comment: Use the stringR package it's part of the TidyVerse: https://stringr.tidyverse.org/articles/regular-expressions.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The select helper function `matches()` is available to match regular expressions:

```r
library(dplyr)

out <- select(iris, matches("s$"))

head(out)
#>   Species
#> 1  setosa
#> 2  setosa
#> 3  setosa
#> 4  setosa
#> 5  setosa
#> 6  setosa
```

Answer (score 2):

With `dplyr`, one can use `ends_with`:

```
iris %>% 
  select(ends_with("s")) %>% 
   head(3)
  Species
1  setosa
2  setosa
3  setosa
```

With `base`  and `grepl`:

```
head(iris[grepl("s$",names(iris),ignore.case = FALSE)])
  Species
1  setosa
2  setosa
3  setosa
4  setosa
5  setosa
6  setosa
```

Or using `purrr`:

```
iris %>% 
   purrr::keep(grepl("s$",names(.))) %>% 
   head()
  Species
1  setosa
2  setosa
3  setosa
4  setosa
5  setosa
6  setosa
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also use `endsWith` from `base R`

```
subset(iris, select = endsWith(names(iris), "s"))
```